# Music-Related Rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus, music

This is a music-related rebus puzzle, for [the fortnight challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion?cb=1) of mixing unconventional tags, hence this music rebus.

[image: Music Rebus]

What famous quote from a movie is suggested in the above rebus?

Comment: If that second bar is meant to be what it looks like, its timing is wrong. (The upper "part" in the left hand needs each of its notes to start a semiquaver earlier, end at the same time, and therefore be a semiquaver longer.)

Comment: Adding on @GarethMcCaughan's comment, this is if the third bar is supposed to be the first bar from prelude no. 1 in C major from Bach's Well-tempered Clavier.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  You are both right— the prelude in C is what I was going for, and there is no puzzley meaning to the note being in the wrong place— I just made a mistake.

Comment: Is the second vertical bar green and outsized on purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In the first measure, **ALL** of the notes on the piano are to be played simultaneously. In the second measure, six **B**s are to be played. The third measure is the first bar of J.S. **Bach**'s Prelude in C from Book 1 of the Well-Tempered Clavier.
>
>  **ALL B BACH**
>
>  This, of course, is in reference to '**I'll Be Back**' from *The Terminator*.

Answer (score 4):

> "I'll be back" (The Terminator) writ large?

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Maybe: First bar "all" notes. Second bar Bs. Last bar Bach. "All B Bach" = "I'll be back".